# Raspcontrol at start up?

Tags: boot, setup, software-installation, web-server

I have following scenario. I cloned Raspcontrol via git, and the repo is now located in /home/pi. Using `ls`, I can see the Raspcontrol folder. Inside, there's a *start.sh* for it to run. I decided to make it run on startup, and I came across this article in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu

So, here's my question:

1. Should I just put replace *filename* with *start.sh*, and run those commands?
2. What is *update-rc.d*?
3. If I don't want to change the structure of Raspcontrol (not moving *start.sh*), what are the other ways to achieve the same thing?

PS: I'm not sure which tag should be used, please edit it if you find it appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Just replace *filename* with *start.sh*.
2. It's like a collection of files. These files are run when changing run levels. Almost like the "startup" folder in Windows, all the files will run everytime a run level is changed. But it's mostly used to run files on startup, which is technically "changing" a run level. Think of it as a pool of files that will be run at startup, files can be removed as well.
3. If you mean that you dont want to move the start.sh file. Then rather use the following command to make the file run at startup

   update-rc.d start.sh defaults

Comment: Thanks, but I do have 2 extra questions, I just need to type update-rc.d <i>filename</i> defaults? Do I need to specify the actual path? Like /home/pi/Rhascontrol/start.sh.

Comment: Yes you must specify the path. But if your in the folder with the start.sh file. you can just type `update-rc.d start.sh defaults`. Meaning that the path to the file can be relative.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually tried to edit my comment, to ask 1 more question, but I get disconnected from my network from the same time. Maybe I will post another question.

Comment: I actually tried the command, but I get the following:
`update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d/start.sh`. Means I still need to put start.sh into /etc/init.d?

Comment: Try running the following 2 commands `sudo update-rc.d rpcbind defaults` and `sudo update-rc.d nfs-common defaults` and then try running the original command.